# Changing the content of the file in python

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to have a script (written in Python) that can change a content of a certain text file according to a database records.

For example: I have a DB that has some records of different types and a script that retrieves a single record from the database and according to that record it automatically changes a content of the text file that is somewhere on the system (e.g. tempo_file.txt).

I know that Python can read from database, read from file and input to the file. But what kind of logic should I apply to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize, when read from I file, you actually read it to the memory. You can manipulate it in your program.

Then you can flush the bytes in your memory into the disk. AKA save it or write it. If you want to "automatically change something", I guess you have to just read from the file and write to the file that has the same name.

There really is no way to manipulate it on the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

> what kind of logic should I apply to overcome this problem?

Well quite simply:

- read from the database
- open the text file
- write to the text file
- close the text file
- lather, rinse, repeat